I can be crooked, I can be slanted
Not at the end, and not at the start
Somewhere within, I am usually at
All of the time I stay kinda low
But double me up, to the top I go
I clarify well, I give you a pause
They call me Mark, that's just because..
I can be crooked, I can be slanted
Guess who I am, and a tick will be granted

You're probably

 a comma? Or possibly an apostrophe, but I think a comma.

Not at the end, and not at the start
Somewhere within, I am usually at

 A comma wouldn't make sense at the start or end of a sentence; it's always somewhere in the middle.

All of the time I stay kinda low

 This is why I went for comma rather than apostrophe.

But double me up, to the top I go

 That would be a " symbol.

I clarify well, I give you a pause

 A comma marks a pause at the end of a clause. (Unlike a cat, which has claws at the end of its paws.)

They call me Mark, that's just because..

 A punctuation mark.

I can be crooked, I can be slanted

 According to the font used.

Guess who I am, and a tick will be granted

 Hopefully, a tick will be granted to this answer.

